# R: find and set to zero each element in a vector that does not appear in another vector

Tags: r, vector

I have two numeric vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b <- c(4,2,2,3,9,10,7,7,10,14)
```

I want to set any number in `b` that does not appear in `a` to zero.
 My desired result is:

```
c <- c(4,2,2,3,0,0,7,7,0,0)
```

who can I do this in an elegant way?

(I was thinking to use left_join but I think there must be some more elegant approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by subsetting `b` with the `%in%` function:

```
b[! b %in% a] <- 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the negation of the `%in%` condition:

```
b[!b %in% a] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

ifelse(b %in% a, b, 0) seems to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(b, !b  %in% a, 0)
```